# PermissionUtils can not be resolved

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to get my current location in my app but I'm getting `PermissionUtils` error. This isn't getting resolved. I got the codes from [google's official github tutorial](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/java/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/MyLocationDemoActivity.java).

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMyLocationClickListener,
        OnMapReadyCallback,
        ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {

    /**
     * Request code for location permission request.
     *
     * @see #onRequestPermissionsResult(int, String[], int[])
     */
    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    /**
     * Flag indicating whether a requested permission has been denied after returning in
     * {@link #onRequestPermissionsResult(int, String[], int[])}.
     */
    private boolean mPermissionDenied = false;

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);
        mMap.setOnMyLocationClickListener(this);
        enableMyLocation();

    }

    private void enableMyLocation() {


        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission to access the location is missing.
            PermissionUtils.requestPermission(this, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, true);
        } else if (mMap != null) {
            // Access to the location has been granted to the app.
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "MyLocation button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Return false so that we don't consume the event and the default behavior still occurs
        // (the camera animates to the user's current position).
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMyLocationClick(@NonNull Location location) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Current location:\n" + location, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        if (requestCode != LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
            return;
        }

        if (PermissionUtils.isPermissionGranted(permissions, grantResults,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)){
            // Enable the my location layer if the permission has been granted.
            enableMyLocation();
        } else {
            // Display the missing permission error dialog when the fragments resume.
            mPermissionDenied = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResumeFragments() {
        super.onResumeFragments();
        if (mPermissionDenied) {
            // Permission was not granted, display error dialog.
            showMissingPermissionError();
            mPermissionDenied = false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Displays a dialog with error message explaining that the location permission is missing.
     */
    private void showMissingPermissionError() {
        PermissionUtils.PermissionDeniedDialog
                .newInstance(true).show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`PermissionUtils` is a class defined by the sample project. If you want to use it, you'll have to copy it to your project.

Answer (score 1):

Do you had set uses permission in manifest? If don't, you should set it first.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```